# Cron job is schedualed but doesn't seem to be running

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a cron job set up to open a webpage in a browser at 11 minutes past everyhour. I can run the script manually and everything works but when it comes to the cron job nothing seems to happen.

I'm a newbie running ubuntu 10.10, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: could you post your cron job setup?

Comment: 11 * * * * home/alex/voteScript.sh

Answer (score 1):

In your crontab, check to make sure that you are using the absolute path (/`usr/bin/run_cron_task.pl`) as oppose to the relative path (`run_cron_task.pl`). That's a common problem.  Also, check to make sure your script is executable, meaning you can run it like `./run_cron_task.pl` as oppose to `perl run_cron_task.pl`.

If it's still not working, post your crontab.

Comment: Yea, based on your comment, you're missing your leading slash. So it should be: `11 * * * * /home/alex/voteScript.sh`

Comment: I was missing the first slash, we'll see if that fixes it

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your job doesn't know what X server the browse should use to display the webpage. Check the DISPLAY environment variable.